# Speeding up a Python datetime comparison to generate values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, comparison, analytics

I want to do this in a pythonic way without using 1) a nested if statement and 2) the use of iterrows.

I have columns

```
Date in | Date Out | 1/22 | 2/22 | ... | 12/22
1/1/19    5/5/22
5/5/22    7/7/22
```

for columns like '1/22', I want to insert a calculated value which would be one of the following:

1. Not Created Yet
2. Closed
3. Open

For the first row,  column 1/22 would read "Open" because it was opened in Jan/22. This would continue until column 5/22, in which it would be labeled "Closed."

For the second row, column 1/22 would read "Not Created Yet" until 5/22 which would read "Open" until 7/22 which would have the value "Closed."

I don't need the full table necessarily, but I want to get a count of how many are closed/open/not created yet for every month.

Here is the code I'm using which works, but just takes longer than I think it could:

```
table={}
for i in mcLogsClose.iterrows():
    table[i[0]] = {}
    for month in pd.date_range(start='9/2021', end='9/2022', freq='M'):
        if i[1]['Notif Date'] <= month:
            if i[1]['Completion Date'] <= month:
                table[i[0]][month]="Closed"
            else:
                table[i[0]][month]="Open"
        else:
            table[i[0]][month]="Not Yet Created"
```

I then want to run `table['1/22'].value_counts()`

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: (1) your data does not match up with the explanation of what you want (2) if you simply want to count how many months are in each status per row, there are much simpler options instead of creating the columns

Comment: "there are much simpler options instead of creating the columns"
i'm listening.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Using a loop

```py
# The date range you are calculating for
min_date = pd.Period("2022-01")
max_date = pd.Period("2022-12")
span = (max_date - min_date).n + 1

# Strip the "Date In" and "Date Out" columns down to the month
date_in = pd.to_datetime(df["Date In"]).dt.to_period("M")
date_out = pd.to_datetime(df["Date Out"]).dt.to_period("M")

data = []
for d_in, d_out in zip(date_in, date_out):
    if d_in > max_date:
        # If date in is after max date, the whole span is under "Not Created" status
        data.append((span, 0, 0))
    elif d_out < min_date:
        # If date out is before min date, the whole span is under "Closed" status
        data.append((0, span, 0))
    else:
        # Now that we have some overlap between (d_in, d_out) and (min_date,
        # max_date), we need to calculate time spent in each status
        closed = (max_date - min(d_out, max_date)).n
        not_created = (max(d_in, min_date) - min_date).n
        open_ = span - closed - not_created
        data.append((not_created, closed, open_))

cols = ["Not Created Yet", "Closed", "Open"]
df[cols] = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols, index=df.index)
```

#### 2. Using numpy

```py
def to_n(arr: np.array) -> np.array:
    """Convert an array of pd.Period to array of integers"""
    return np.array([i.n for i in arr])

# The date range you are calculating for. Since we intend to use vectorized
# code, we need to turn them into numpy arrays
min_date = np.repeat(pd.Period("2022-01"), len(df))
max_date = np.repeat(pd.Period("2022-12"), len(df))
span = to_n(max_date - min_date) + 1

date_in = pd.to_datetime(df["Date In"]).dt.to_period("M")
date_out = pd.to_datetime(df["Date Out"]).dt.to_period("M")

df["Not Created Yet"] = np.where(
    date_in > max_date,
    span,
    to_n(np.max([date_in, min_date], axis=0) - min_date),
)
df["Closed"] = np.where(
    date_out < min_date,
    span,
    to_n(max_date - np.min([date_out, max_date], axis=0)),
)
df["Open"] = span - df["Not Created Yet"] - df["Closed"]
```

Result (with some rows added for my testing):

```
  Date In  Date Out  Not Created Yet  Closed  Open
0  1/1/19    5/5/22                0       7     5
1  5/5/22    7/7/22                4       5     3
2  1/1/20  12/12/20                0      12     0
3  1/1/23    6/6/23               12       0     0
4  6/6/21    6/6/23                0       0    12
```